# Wrong result after add em remove object from ArrayList

Tags: java, object, arraylist, process, conditional-statements

My code shows a inconsistente result. When I run it, the if operation executes only when `incoming.get(i).getSubmitionTime()` is odd.

That is my code:

```
public void decrementIncoming () {
    for (int i = 0; i < incoming.size(); i++) {
        incoming.get(i).setSubmitionTime(incoming.get(i).getSubmitionTime() - 1);
        if (incoming.get(i).getSubmitionTime() == 0 ) {
            Process p = incoming.get(i);                
            incoming.remove(i);
            ready.add(p);
        }
    }
}
```

The result is

```
----- Time 6 -----
----- Running -----
1 : 5
----- Ready -----
3 : 6
5 : 6
7 : 8
----- Blocked -----
----- Incoming -----
2 : 6
4 : 6
6 : 8
8 : 8
```

But all of them have to come into state ready in the same time.
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly is this (confusing) line of code intended to achieve: `incoming.get(i).setSubmitionTime(incoming.get(i).getSubmitionTime() - 1);`?

Comment: Post the complete code

Comment: @Kon Think of it as `if(--incoming[i].submitionTime == 0) {`

Comment: Did you getting any error in code if yes can you post it here

Comment: Side note: you can reduce the code inside the `if` to `ready.add(incoming.remove(i))`.

Comment: I'm assuming the rightmost number in each line of the result is the `submitionTime` from each item?

Comment: Anyway your question is completely unclear. You're assuming we know a lot more about your code than we actually do. For example, you're asking about your output, yet your code doesn't even have a print statement. Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because when you call `incoming.remove(i);` you need to decrement `i` counter as well. But better solution is using iterator:

```
public void decrementIncoming () {

    Iterator<Process> processIterator = incoming.iterator();
    while (processIterator.hasNext()) {
        Process process = processIterator.next();
        process.setSubmitionTime(process.getSubmitionTime() - 1);
        if (process.getSubmitionTime() == 0 ) {                
            processIterator.remove();
            ready.add(process);
        }
    }
}
```